# Unable to pass authentication paramethers inside Python SOAP call

Tags: python, python-2.7, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have an WSDL file

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:TestWebService">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:AuthenticationInfo>
         <urn:userName>test</urn:userName>
         <urn:password>test</urn:password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:authentication></urn:authentication>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:locale></urn:locale>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:timeZone></urn:timeZone>
      </urn:AuthenticationInfo>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:Pokupi>
         <urn:Request_ID__c>000000000000141</urn:Request_ID__c>
      </urn:Pokupi>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My code in Python is following:

```
#import zeep
from suds.client import Client
from suds import WebFault
from suds.sax.element import Element

url = 'http://bmc2012.comtrade.co.yu:8080/arsys/WSDL/public/BMC2012/TestWebService'
user = "test"
password = "test"

ssnp = Element("xsi:AuthenticationInfo").append(Element('xsi:userName').setText(user))
ssnp = Element("xsi:AuthenticationInfo").append(Element('xsi:password').setText(password))
client = Client(url)
client.set_options(soapheaders=ssnp)

record = client.factory.create('Pokupi')
result = client.service.Pokupi(record)
print result

#client = zeep.Client(url)
#print (client.service.Pokupi('000000000000141'))
```

Instead of getting data in response, I constantly get error message:
   A user name must be supplied in the control record

I tried both with zeep and suds library, but I cannot pass this message. When I do this call inside of SOPA UI, I get no errors.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

I have faced similar issue. Following are the steps I followed to solve the issue (I have used "zeep" a 3rd party module to solve this):

1. Run the following command to understand my **WSDL**:

   `python -mzeep **wsdl_url**`

   (in your case **wsdl_url** would be http://bmc2012.comtrade.co.yu:8080/arsys/WSDL/public/BMC2012/TestWebService)
2. We can search for string "Service:".  Below that we can see our operation name (I guess your operation is "Pokupi").
3. For my operation I found following entry:

   `MyOperation(param1 xsd:string, _soapheaders={parameters: ns0:AuthenticationInfo})`

   which clearly communicates that, I have to pass one string param and an auth param using kwargs "_soapheaders"
4. With that I came to know that I have to pass my authentication element as _soapheaders argument to MyOperation function.
5. Created Auth Element:

   `auth_ele = client.get_element('ns0:AuthenticationInfo')
     auth = auth_ele(userName='me', password='mypwd')`
6. Passed the auth to my Operation:

   `cleint.service.MyOperation('param1_value', _soapheaders=[auth])`

I got the the expected result. Though this a late reply, I thought this would help few people who suffer like me.