# Can't invoke Soap method with Zeep and basic auth

Tags: basic-authentication, zeep

I am trying to access Web Service with Zeep and I get 401 in response. I checked official docs and https://stackoverflow.com/a/48861779/9187682 . I get an error when I try to call a method, like:

```py
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth  # or HTTPDigestAuth, or OAuth1, etc.
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user, password)
client = Client('http://my-endpoint.com/production.svc?wsdl',
    transport=Transport(session=session))

Items = client.get_type('ns1:ItemsType')
response = client.service.publishService('MyProps', Items ={ #ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    'ItemInformation': {
        '':''
    }
})
```

The response I get is:

```
zeep.exceptions.TransportError: Server returned response (401) with invalid XML: Invalid XML content received (Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1).
```

Request in itself is OK (it works without auth if it's disabled on service).

Credentials are OK as well (in fact the whole thing works in Soap UI)

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You got it worked? I have same issue here